# Parsing mysql date to ZonedDateTime

Tags: java, mysql, datetime-parsing, zoneddatetime

I'm trying to parse data coming from MySql in the following format:

```
DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%m-%d-%Y %H:%i')
```

Java parser code looks like this:

```
ZonedDateTime datetime = ZonedDateTime
                    .parse(
                            row[1].toString(), 
                            DateTimeFormatter
                                    .ofPattern("MM-dd-YYYY hh:mm")
                                    .withZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/GMT"))
                    );
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06-08-2017 04:15' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain ZonedDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {MinuteOfHour=15, DayOfMonth=8, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2017, MonthOfYear=6, HourOfAmPm=4},ISO,Etc/GMT of type java.time.format.Parsed

Is there a better/shorter way to get this done?

Comment: Read it as a `java.sql.Date`, and convert that to a `ZonedDateTime`.

Comment: Not everything you read from database must come as a string. Sql has native date-time types, and you should definitely use them.

Comment: Elliott, java.sql.Date does not have a time component in it

Comment: Before you resort to outdated classes like `java.sql.Date` and friends, check if you have or can get a JDBC driver that can give you an instance of the modern classes like `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` (requires JDBC 4.2 compliance, so I’ve read).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local repair to your problem is:

```
    ZonedDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.parse(row[1].toString(), 
                    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-uuuu HH:mm"))
            .atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

Please note that I have changed `YYYY` to `uuuu` and `hh` to uppercase `HH` in your format pattern. `Y` is used for *week-based-year*, and `h` is used for *clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12)* which does not make sense without `a` (the symbol for am/pm marker). Learn more about these symbols from [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).

Edit: I was taking my mouth too full here. Your own Java code works nicely with just these two changes to your format pattern. I will let my version of the code stand in case anyone can take inspiration from it.

That said, the best solution is to get for example an `Instant` object from your JDBC driver rather than a string that is formatted on the database side and parsed back on the Java side. A JDBC 4.2 compliant driver should be able to give you that.

Comment: This is what i ended up doing: 
ZonedDateTime dt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(rs.getTimestamp("datetime").toInstant(), UTCZONEID)

Comment: That looks like an improvement over the way you tried to make work before. Clearer and simpler. Another thing I like about it is that the `java.sql.Timestamp` you obtain, the first thing you do with it is convert it to `Instant` so to minimize your use of the old class.